# Error al levantar passenger al instalar canvas-lms

Tags: canvas

ya e reinstalado passenger y realize configuraciones extra de la documentacion oficial de canvas-lms pero el error persiste

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sudo passenger-status

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.